# Custom fonts not getting uploaded in Openshift server

Tags: tomcat6, openshift

I have developed an application which uses custom CSS3 fonts. But somehow custom fonts are not getting uploaded in the server. My application URL is http://techcurt-kshitiz.rhcloud.com and when I try to access custom font like http://techcurt-kshitiz.rhcloud.com/resources/css/LindenHill-webfont.eot, The requested resource is not available appears. Custom fonts are working fine in my local machine in every browser.

I have recreated my application but still the problem persists. I have been using Openshift since an year but never faced such issue. What can be the possible reason for it? Even .less file is not getting uploaded. I am using tomcat 6 server in Openshift. I am not able to find out any solution in Google.

Comment: I have created a similar application http://techcurta-kshitiz1.rhcloud.com and there, custom fonts are working fine!!! But if you check out http://techcurt-kshitiz.rhcloud.com, they are not being uploaded. What can be the reason behind it? Both the applications are from different account (or PC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally my issue is solved by servlet-mapping .ttf and .eot files in my web.xml files. But I am not able to understand how come my application was running in local machine but not in server? How come thats possible?

Answer (score 1):

Do you see the files on disk when you SSH to the gear?

Are the files checked into Git?  It's possible that they are being ignored by git, and hence not uploaded.  You can check that the file is in git with "git show master:" - if ignored it won't show up.

Otherwise, it could be something in your build - perhaps the files are getting deleted?